# htaccess query string to text

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm having some problems with my .htaccess.

I have a link that's:

```
domain/view.php?pid=2
```

And I want to change it simply to:

```
domain/2
```

I don't have much knowledge with .htaccess and my attempts didn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$1 /view.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

I have another link that is

```
click.php?bid=2
```

and would like to transform it into

```
/out/2
```

Please note that my website (with exception of links view.php and click.php) works like: index.php?id=page1/2/3... Maybe it could be important in this thing. I just want to change view.php and click.php files.

Could someone help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.
Could just someone check it to see if there's any big flaw or something?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ view.php?pid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^out/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ click.php?bid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: If bid and pid values are strictly integers, use just 0-9 in square brackets, `[0-9]`

Comment: I've changed it but if the value doesnt exists gives an error. If I stay with all chars if the "ID" doesnt exist it redirects me to index what's intended for. If I only allow numbers if I type chars it doesnt redirect me to index and give error. Thanks :)